# Domain Controller Demoted - But did not tranfer the FSMO Roles

Tags: active-directory

I am in the learning stage of Active Directory. There are tow DCs in my domain. DC1 and DC2. DC1 is holding the FSMO Roles. I Forgot to transfer the FSMO Roles to DC2 and demoted the DC1. Now the DC2 says "domain cannot be contacted or does not exists" and some other warnings like "naming context path not correct, configuration context path not correct". Can any one suggest how can i seize FSMO Roles in DC2 and create default application partition in DC2

Answer (score 0):

To [seize the FSMO roles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255504):

1. Run `ntdsutil` on DC2
2. Type **roles**, press Enter
3. Type **connections**, press Enter
4. Type **connect to DC2**, press Enter
5. Type **q**, press Enter
6. Type **?** to see the FSMO roles you can seize using the **seize** command
7. Seize the appropriate roles

> [...] and create default application partition in DC2

Not entirely sure what you mean. If DC2 does not already have a replica of the default naming context partition (in other words, if it is not already a Domain Controller in the same domain as DC1), seizing the FSMO Roles will never work.

Comment: it does have. i mean performed replication between those DC's. While doing some FSMO roles exercises, forgot to transfer them. did the above you mentioned. Transfer "FSMO Role Name" commands for all 5 roles. Still if i try to open Active Directory Users and Computers - it says "naming information could not be located because the specified domain does not exists or could not be contacted. @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: can i transfer those roles to DC2. (though that DC1 is demoted) ? @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: No, since DC1 is dead, you can't *transfer* them, you can *seize* them. Make sure that the NIC on DC2 points to itself for DNS

Comment: Not worked. System Formatted and created new Forest. @Mathias R. Jessen